# Magento: how to transform price in indian format ( in lakh system Rs 1,11,111)?

Tags: php, magento

Magento: how to transform price in indian format ( in lakh system Rs 1,11,111) ?

Answer (score 2):

After some debugging , i found the solution , hope it will help you guys too

Magento 1.9 (Locale - en_US )

1) Goto lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

2) Replace Line: 2611 `<pattern>¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)</pattern>` with `<pattern>¤#,##,##0.00;(¤#,##,##0.00)</pattern>`

3) Clear the var/cache

4) done